# Data retrieval using Parse in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I did this for fetching data and showing it in a table view 
but it's not showing anything.

I used this code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Bolts

class Parsedata: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    //@IBOutlet var NTableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet var NTableView: UITableView!
    var NArray:[String] = [String]()




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.NTableView.delegate = self
        self.NTableView.dataSource = self


        // retrieve notification from parse
        self.RetrieveN()
        NSLog("Done with it")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func RetrieveN () {

        //create a pfquery
        var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Notification")

        //call findobject in background
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

            //clear the Narray

            self.NArray = [String]()

            //loop through the objects array
            for Nobject in objects!{

                //retrieve the text column value of each PFobject
                let Ntext:String? = (Nobject as! PFObject) ["Text"] as? String


                // assign it into your Narray

                if Ntext != nil {
                self.NArray.append(Ntext!)

                }

            }

            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) Notifications.")}
           //reload the table view
            self.NTableView.reloadData()
            }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.NTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NCell") as UITableViewCell?

        cell?.textLabel?.text = self.NArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell!

    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return NArray.count
    }
}
```

It's working fine because it's showing that 3 objects were retrieved on the LOG container.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have more code than what's posted here, you also need to implement `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and return 1

Comment: hey there ? what could be the more code ?? and i implemented now numberofselection with returning value 1 , and still its not showing any thing in my tableview ? i don't know what to do  i think its just finding the objects in background but not populating it in tableview . so can you help me with this ? like how to populate this objects into tableview

Answer (score 0):

I have just learnt how to do this myself, this is how you can load data from parse and save it as a NSMutableArray then use that data to populate your table view.

```
let NArray : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
```

then you can use your query you made with

```
var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Notification")

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock( { (AnyObject objects, NSError error) in
        if error == nil {
            self.NArray = NSMutableArray(array: objects!)
            self.NTableView.reloadData()
        } else {
          print(error?.localisedDescription)
    })
```

this will load all your content into the variable NArray, which you can then use in your tableView function with indexPath. That line of code inside your tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath would be

```
cell?.textLabel?.text = self.NArray[indexPath.row] //you may have to cast this as? String
```

Like i said this is how i am loading my data, i am using this to load PFUser usernames, profile pictures etc and displaying them in a custom table view cell.
You may have to slightly tweak these methods but the base methods are there

Comment: heY can you share with me the full code ?? m not getting it how to do it correctly :( and thanks for helping me

Comment: okay just so i can get the right info what is your class tables setup like in parse?

Comment: hey thanks for helping :) but i already find a solution for it :)